# Tools to convert from TEX to XSL-FO format for TOC template

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, two-column, conversion, xml

I need to get an `XSL-FO` (XSL Formatting Objects) template of a TOC (Table of Contents) with two columns and for various reason I would like to obtain it starting from an equivalent template written in `.tex` format, is there any tool/idea to get it done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!